# Div not resetting its default position after altered using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a overlay with empty height and width that covers the whole page once its clicked using a button, this overlay transition from **top 0** **left 0** all the way down to bottom right. once this over lay is closed I edited the css property using java script so that it transition finished on the bottom right.

The first time opening and close this overlay, it works fine, however the second time I open it, instead of starting from top left, it starts from bottom right and moves all the way to top left. I cant seem to fix this problem. I try resetting the left to 0 and top to 0 but it doesnt work.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".overlay_background")[0].addEventListener("click", parent);
   

function parent(event) {
  this.style.left = this.clientWidth + "px";
  this.style.top = this.clientHeight + "px";
  this.style.height = 0;
  this.style.width = 0;
}

function child(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}

function http_request_availability() {
  document.getElementById("overlay_background_id").style.left = "0";
  document.getElementById("overlay_background_id").style.top = "0";
  console.log(document.getElementById("overlay_background_id"));
  document.getElementById("overlay_background_id").style.height = "100vh";
  document.getElementById("overlay_background_id").style.width = "100vw";

  document.getElementById("overlay_background_id").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0, 0.5)";
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";


}
```

```css
.overlay_background {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.7s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay_background" id="overlay_background_id">
  Hi this is my overlay
</div>
<button class='btn_ws' onclick='http_request_availability();'>Book Work-Shop</button></div>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined`. Missing `.overlay_ws_container`

Comment: I removed that bit of code. try again :)

Comment: This is because you never set the left + top property back to 0 when closing inside the parent, which you can't, because it would interfere with the current animation to top down.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain, I kinda thought about that, but im not sure how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your overlay never resets to its original position of top 0 and left 0.

Try adding this to the end of your parent() function:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    self.style.left = 0;
    self.style.top = 0;
 }, 700);
```

This will reset the left and top positions to 0 after 700 ms has passed (the duration of the transition).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i was thinking of something like this but didnt know if i was right. I was also thinking of constantly adding left 0 and top 0 each time the mouse move inside the webpage, but i figure that is a bad way of doing it :)